# ¿Como cierro una modal al momento de presionar un boton de tipo submit?

Tags: php, ajax, datatables, bootstrap-4, modal

necesito que me asesoren como hago para cerrar una venta modal al momento de hacer click a un boton

Estaba probando con `myModal.hide()` pero no se cierra

Comment: Será más fácil que podamos ayudarte si nos das más detalles. ¿Qué es lo que tienes ahora? ¿Puedes compartir la pieza de código relevante? ¿Qué has probado?

Comment: @ArianJM agregue codigo donde se hace el proceso de guardar, lo que necesito es que cierre la modal automaticamente cuando se envia el formulario

Comment: No se cierra con `myModal.hide()` porque ese no es el identificador de tu modal. Si estás usando AJAX, puedes cerrarlo en caso que se cumpla la funcion guardar(e), algo así como `$("#add_categoria").modal("hide");`

Comment: En todo caso, por favor dale en [edit] tu pregunta, para añadir cómo estás intentando cerrarlo desde el JS. En lo posible, te recomiendo crear un [example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te pongo un ejemplo de abrir y cerrar modal con los botones. No tengo claro si es lo que quieres, pero quizá te ayude a encontrar lo que buscas.

```js
function cerrarModal() {
  $('#fondo-modal').hide();
}

function abrirModal() {
  const $modal = $('#fondo-modal');
  $modal.show();
  $modal.css('display', 'flex');
}

const $botonAbrir = $('#pagina button');
const $botonCerrar = $('#contenido-modal button').eq(0);

// Click en abrir modal
$botonAbrir.on('click', () => {
  abrirModal();
});

// Click en cerrar
$botonCerrar.on('click', () => {
  cerrarModal();
});
```

```css
#fondo-modal {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#contenido-modal {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="pagina">
  <p>Contenido de mi página</p>
  <button>Abrir modal</button>
</div>

<div id="fondo-modal">
  <div id="contenido-modal">
    <h1>¿Seguro?</h1>
    <p>¿Seguro que quieres hacer esta acción?</p>
    <div>
      <button>Cerrar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```